# Mitigating the misbehaviour of the non-client portion of an application window

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32

I have a program that has some rather bad window handling. I can provide scripting to the client portion of the application but have no control over the non-client portion, apart from some simple movement/resizing commands (that don't help).

The main problem is that when the windows "maximize" button is pressed the WS_MAXIMIZE style is not set. The window is positioned correctly, and helpfully respects the taskbar settings but the application icon/title and "windows buttons" are misplaced and the borders show up on any other screens.

Using winspy++ I was able to set the WS_MAXIMIZE style fixing these graphical annoyances. but this also led into a secondary issue. The "restore" button also does nothing, when pressed it simply reverts the style and does not take the application back to it's pre-maximized position and size.

I was going to make a launcher for this program in Python anyway, to handle some .ini stuff and alterable executable parameters.

I would like to extend this launcher to silently run behind the application, fixing these issues.

These things were intended to be handled by the operating system and the developers of the application do not seem to be focused on working on these problems, but more on increasing the library of application scripting and porting to other systems.

My assumption is that when the launcher is commanded to run the program it needs to have access to the thread/process so that it can poll the position and size of the application window and set the appropriate style when it is required, and more importantly (I guess), have access to it's memory.

Example: [-8,-8] to [1374,776] on a 1366x768 screen with a minimized taskbar.

If there is an asynchronous method to detect when the window has been moved/resized/windows buttons pressed, that would be preferable to polling every step.

Supplying the window with "restore" information to make use of the restore button seems a bit less trivial. I have been reading as much reference as I can find but have not found anything on this. Where is this memory stored? How do I access it? Is it read-only, and only set by the OS?

I'm new to Python, and SO, so I apologize if my question doesn't fit here, I've tried.

Comment: Proper maximize/restore handling comes for free courtesy of the window manager, an application has to go out of its way to get this wrong. I'm not sure Python is the solution for anything however.

Comment: @Jonathan, that was somewhere along my line of thought, the developers of said application chose this for some obscure reason or really messed something up.